# How can I use Open/Save to file with System.Drawing.Image?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, webforms

I am using `System.Drawing.Image` to generate an image and I know that you can use `System.Drawing.Image.Save("<directory>");` to save it to a specified file.

The problem is that I want to the user to get a prompt asking them whether they would like to open or save the file so they can choose where to save it.

Comment: @RobertoConteRosito Read the tags. **Web** forms not **Win** forms.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Where is this image coming from? Can't you just treat it like a file?

Comment: It's browser setting that will it open or save.

Comment: I am generating the image which is fine but I need it to output the the user so they can save it, at the moment the image.save needs a directory so all I can do right now is have the user manually enter a destination to save the file to. @Șhȇkhaṝ it's not a browser setting, nothing is being output right now it is serverside.

Comment: @connersz is this a web application or windows?

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ it's a web application, did you see the tags?

Comment: @connersz and to which user you want to save the image. See you can not prompt for location to save file in between a process. What you can do is first ask for location and then save it on that location. But you will not be able to save it on all the location.